# Catastrophic failures within a "using" statement i.e. using(var a= new stream()) and a.Something() throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using, finalize

So I understand that at the end of a using block statement, the dispose method is called.

What happens if I use a `'using(var a = new Stream()) { a.SomethingThrowsAnException() }'`

Does the stream just still go through he dispose method?

I wrote a class that implements IDisposable, and it is mission critical I do not lose what's in memory, so I was planning on serializing the data if something catastrophic happens i.e. I have a custom stream like object I am using.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is answered in every tutorial and many, many SO questions.

Comment: True, I should have taken the time to write a console application demonstrating this to myself.

Comment: Note that using `using` still isn't a magic bullet for every type of catastrophic failure. Some exceptions just can't be handled gracefully (eg, `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException` etc). And of course, no amount of clever code can save you if somebody pulls the plug on your mission-critical machine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The `using` block compiles down to this:

```
var a = new Stream();
try
{
     a.SomethingThrowsAnException();
}
finally
{
     a.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The `finally` block also includes an `a != null` check for reference type `IDisposable`s so that this won't throw an exception: `using ((IDisposable)null) { }` (or you use a method that returns a null).

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a situation in which the finally clause ends up executed by a different thread (I have a separate question posted on this issue).  It can matter because some operations, such as lock.release, need to occur on the same thread that did the lock.acquire. I'm not sure precisely what causes this, or how to delay the thread termination to ensure that a.Dispose occurs on the thread that did the original new operation...